# How to return an array of child objects from a parent object

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm creating a web application. I have some data from the backend and I have to manipulate it to create my front end application the problem demo is shown below.

I have an object something like in javascript

```
[
  {
    id: "1",
    projectId: "1",
    user: {
      id: "123",
      firstName: "aaaa",
      lastName: "bbb",
      title: "SE"
    }
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    projectId: "2",
    user: {
      id: "456",
      firstName: "ccc",
      lastName: "fff",
      title: "QA"
    }
  }
]
```

I need to convert this to:

```
[
  {
    id: "123",
    firstName: "aaaa",
    lastName: "bbb",
    title: "SE"
  },
  {
    id: "456",
    firstName: "ccc",
    lastName: "fff",
    title: "QA"
  }

]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you have an array of objects and you want to access an object inside this element 
you can do this

```
const newData = data.map(({user})=>user)
```

Comment: Damn buddy, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

`map` over your original data and return only the `user` object

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: "1",
    projectId: "1",
    user: {
      id: "123",
      firstName: "aaaa",
      lastName: "bbb",
      title: "SE"
    }
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    projectId: "2",
    user: {
      id: "456",
      firstName: "ccc",
      lastName: "fff",
      title: "QA"
    }
  }
]

const mapped = data.map(obj => obj.user)

console.log(mapped)
```

Comment: data.map(t=>t.user)  since all properties belong to user

Comment: Didn't realize that. Thank you